# ManyToMany relation and save objects

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a manyToMany relationship between two entities: **team** and **person**. I have created a method to add a person to a team.

If I create this method only in one service (team), can I add persons to teams and teams to person if I have a manyToMany relationship or do I need to create the same method in person service ?

This is my method:

```
public void addPersonsToTeams(Long teamId, Long personId) {
        Assert.notNull(personId, "Object can't be null!");
        Assert.notNull(teamId, "Object can't be null!");
        try {
            Person person = personRepository.getOne(personId);
            Team team = teamRepository.getOne(teamId);
            person.getTeams().add(team);
            personRepository.save(person);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CreateEntityException();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you asking if this will properly persist the data to the database? Also, please add other relevant tags for the frameworks you are using, like jpa, hibernate, etc.

Comment: Yes from both sites. So i don't need create that kind of method in person service?

Comment: Assuming that you have a join table, this should properly insert a new entry to that join table, which, I think, should be all that you need. But, as always, the best way to make sure is by actually (test) running it.

Comment: Yes i know but to runing this i need res cotroller method(i think POST) but i don't know how to wrote that kind of method:/

Comment: If it runs successfully, it's good. If it fails, we can help you to fix it. But if you can't run it then there is nothing we can do. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** From https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224047/nikolay-shevchenko comment I understand that the ORM framework may solve the many to many synchronization issue by itself. I assume as well it would manage the locking issues associated. I will let my previous answer anyway as I think it is still a good design problem.

First you should avoid including one object into another if they have different life cycles. You should simply reference the other object by Id. You should have a look at the concept of [aggregate](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838). Now I do not know how the underlying ORM you are using will manage this.

To be concrete, this is wrong imo

```
Team team = teamRepository.getOne(teamId);
person.getTeams().add(team);
personRepository.save(person);
```

Because (at least in the code) it seems you are storing a copy of the team object inside a person in your repository. But the team object can be modified outside of this context. For example the team can have a new person. Then your person object will contain a team object out of sync with the one stored in the team repository. You end up with 2 different team objects stored in different places. Now again if your ORM framework solves that for you then you are probably good but I think you should still consider redesigning your code and avoid letting your ORM solves that kind of dilemma.

I would code something like this instead

```
if(teamRepository.contains(teamId)){
    person.getTeamIds().add(teamId);
    personRepository.save(person);
}
```

Now to have the team object also synchronized you could use some kind of domain event. Listen to it in the team service and do the opposite operation inside the team service. But if this sync operation is done in a different transaction which will probably be the case, then it means that at some point your DB is not consistent. This may be a problem or not for you. Also what happens if your backend crashes between the sync operation etc...

So I think you should challenge your design and the fact that team and person services are separate. Maybe they are part of the same service or even aggregate and then you can update them at the same time ?

This is a vast design question and I suggest to have a look at what is an aggregate and read about [domain driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

Hope this will help :)

Comment: `Because you are storing a copy of the team object inside a person in your repository`. Many-to-many relations usually use joint table with 2 FKs, so there is no "copy of object". If IDs of two managed instances of same class are equal then Hibernate considers them to be the same instace. So your example is of no-ORM style

Comment: It is true I do not know how hibernate would do that, I will rephrase. Nevertheless IMO it is a bad practice to assume hibernate is going to solve your problem of design for you.